# can't get data from Database with html and connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, database-connection

I am new to java and having a problem getting data from MySQL.

I can make the connection and they are waiting but can't get the data from the database

[image: GetCompanyById Java class]

[image: GetCompanyById html file]

[image: Database table]

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data from a Sql Db you first need to open a connection. Create a class such as below:

```
 public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://url";
    public static final String USER = "user";
    public static final String PASS = "pass";
    public ConnectionFactory()

 {
        }



        public  Connection getConnection() {
            try {
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
                return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error connecting to the database", ex);
            }}
```

then another class to control that connection to the DB and get whatever info you may need. in your case it's getCompanyById:

```
    public class DbController implements Serializable{

        private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();

        public boolean getCompanyById(int id){
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                Statement stmt = null;
                //connect to database
                Connection conn = connectionFactory.getConnection();
                System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
// cast results to Resultset
                Resultset resultset = stmt.executeQuery(""SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE ID ="+Id+"");

//Iterate through the results creating a new Company object for each set of results and then add them to an ArrayList to filter later on.
          while (resultSet.next()) {
                Company company = new Company();
                company.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                company.setCap(resultSet.getDouble("cap"));
                company.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));
                company.setMinimum(resultSet.getDouble("minimum"));
                 companyList.add(margin);
}

                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Disconnected from database...");
                result = true;
            }
            catch (SQLException exception){
                System.out.println("invalid sql data - remove expense: " + exception.getMessage());
            }

            return result;
        }
```

After this you can cast to HTML in whatever way you need too from Java instead of straight from SQL.

Hopefully this helps.